# TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function: http.createServer

Tags: node.js

When I am trying to use `options` in [`http.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener):

```
http.createServer({
  IncomingMessage: http.IncomingMessage,
  ServerResponse: http.ServerResponse
}, (req, res) => {
 // use req, res
});
```

I get an error: `TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function`.
Is it a bug of node?

Comment: Which version of the node.js do you have? Option argument is since v9.6.0

Comment: Yes, I've updated node and it works now, thanks.
P.S. actually this argument is since v8.x(at least)